# How to substract numbers from a text file to another?

Tags: python

So i have to read from a text file who containts this lines:

```
4-1
12-3
```

After i read that file, i have to write in another file, the result of the lines. e.g. ->

```
4-1=3
12-3=9
```

Till now i have did this code, but i receive some kind of error:

```
with open('C:\users\bacut\Desktop\expresii.txt\', 'r'') as fp:
        for line in enumerate(fp):
            nr1 = 0
            nr2 = 0
            ok = 0
            for c in line:
                if c != '-' and ok == 0:
                    nr1 = nr1 * 10 + int(c)
                if c == '-':
                    ok = 1
                if c  != '-' and ok == 1:
                    nr2 = nr2 * 10 + int(c)
            total = nr1 - nr2
            print("{line}={total}".format(line=line, total=total))
```

This is the error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 
2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

How can i do that? I don't know actually how to write in another file the results, but in my logic this code had to generate at least 12-3=9.
Thanks and i really apreciate your help.

Comment: Post the code you have to far and highlight the part you are struggling with.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "math expression"? Only integer arithmetic as in ``4 - 1``, or more complex operations including variables or integrals? Are the operators the same as in Python, e.g. is ``**`` the power operator?

Comment: Use `r'C:\users\bacut\Desktop\expresii.txt'`. Note the `r` prefix and the deleted trailing backslash. Oh and you also have an extra single quote in `'r''`.

Comment: Done that. Now i get this error: `Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4-1\n'
  File "C:\Users\bacut\Desktop\exercitii programare.py", line 9, in <module>
    nr1 = nr1 * 10 + int(c)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
with open(r'C:\users\bacut\Desktop\expresii.txt', 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            stripline = line.strip()
            linelist = stripline.split("-") # first line: list ["4", "1"]
            result = int(linelist[0]) - int(linelist[1])
            stripline+=("=" + str(result)+"\n")
            with open(r'C:\users\bacut\Desktop\result.txt', 'a') as fr:
                fr.write(stripline)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to run it, but i got this: `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
  File "C:\Users\bacut\Desktop\lista.py", line 3, in <module>
    stripline = line.strip()`

Comment: it is caused by enumerate, now it should be correct

Comment: Thank you, again. Sorry for disturbing you, and i really apreciate the work you did for me. I tried again, now it shows another error: `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
  File "C:\Users\bacut\Desktop\lista.py", line 6, in <module>
    line.append("=" + str(result))`

Comment: I edited the answer, try it now, it works in local for me